# jQuery code to delete all spans with same content but keep one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say i have the following html:

```
<span class="fruit">Apple</span>
<span class="fruit">banana</span>
<span class="fruit">Apple</span>
<span class="fruit">Apple</span>
<span class="fruit">orange</span>
```

I tried different methods but it didn't work, I want a jQuery code to remove all (.fruit) spans with same content but keep one (the first if possible), so i will end up with the following:

```
<span class="fruit">Apple</span>
<span class="fruit">banana</span>
<span class="fruit">orange</span>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

```
 $("span.fruit:contains(Apple):not(:first)").remove();
```

Comment: I love it when this guys seems to speak selectors rather than writing it. lol
and of course love jquery which makes all this so easy. can easily imagine a speech recognition software that you say get all the span removed and keep one and just does this. hehe

Comment: This works for the specific case, but not for the general case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span.fruit').each(function(){
  return $('span.fruit:contains('+$(this).text()+'):not(:first)').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = array[];

$(".fruit").each(function(i) {
    var html = $($this).html();
    if($.inArray(html, temp)) {
        $($this).remove();
    }
    else {
        temp.push(html);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = $('span:first').clone(true);
//remove all the span
$().html();
$().append(temp);
```